# How to Split an ArrayList to get the required data and store it in a String in order to prepare a print command in Android using Java?

Tags: java, android, regex, string, arraylist

I would like to print the items in a List using a Bluetooth POS printer from my application.
I am creating a print command which contains the list of items contained in the List.
I have converted my list to a string. Now i want to get the only required data from that and i have to append print commands to it.
For Example: (Below is the sample output of my list which i converted to String)

```
[{quantity=1, name= C D M roast almond 38g, price=45.0}, {quantity=1, name=Amul cheese 200g, price=105.0}, {quantity=1, name=Bambino roasted vermicelli 170g, price=23.0}, {quantity=1, name=Cadbury shots, price=5.0}, {quantity=1, name=Cherry blk wax 40g, price=51.0}, {quantity=1, name=Clinic plus 175ml, price=95.0}]
```

My Output Should be like below

```
<LEFT>1 <CENTER>C D M roast almond 38g <RIGHT>45.0<BR>
<LEFT>1 <CENTER>Amul cheese 200g <RIGHT>105.0<BR>
<LEFT>1 <CENTER>Bambino roasted vermicelli 170g <RIGHT>23.0<BR>
<LEFT>1 <CENTER>Cadbury shots <RIGHT>5.0<BR>
<LEFT>1 <CENTER>Cherry blk wax 40g <RIGHT>51.0<BR>
<LEFT>1 <CENTER>Clinic plus 175ml <RIGHT>95.0<BR>
```

Here

`<LEFT>, <RIGHT>, <CENTER>, and <BR>`
 are print commands.

I need your help in achieving this.
Below is the image view
[image: List items to be Printed in a bill]

Comment: Why convert it from a list to an incorrect string as a first step, when you could convert it to a correct string instead? Also, don't add tags that have nothing to do with answering your actual question.

Comment: since your list data appears to be in JSON (assuming from above example) you can convert each item from list to a json object and then break them down using getString and prepend required tags i.e <CENTER> <LEFT> etc.

Comment: can you please elaborate it. Please suggest any best possible solution. Instead of converting a list to string. But, ultimately i need a string which holds the entire data to send it for printing. @PatrickParker

Comment: @MohammedJunaid No, Its not a JSON its an ArrayList (ArrayList<Map<String, String>>)